# XLIFF file, keys and long strings with NSLocalizedString

Tags: ios, cocoa, localization, translation, xliff

I want to move to xliff instead of translating `Localizable.strings` and `Main.strings` files but I found out that I'm using `NSLocalizedString` in an improper way (and I did it for 5 years actually...).

I don't like to have the translations directly inside my code, so I use a generic key and I do not write any comments:

`NSLocalizedString("general.error", comment: "")`

Then I include the string into the Localizable.strings

`"general.error" = "An error occured";`

So far so good (maybe). Now when I export xliff files I see that the `source` is just my generic key and obviously a translator cannot guess what to write as `target` for that key :/

So my question is: Is the only solution to move all the translations directly inside the `NSLocalizedString`?

`NSLocalizedString("An error occured", comment: "")`

or inside the comment... (I really don't like this solution)

And what if the string is really long? it seems so strange to put a string of 3 rows directly into the code :/

Any other interesting solution out there?

#### EDIT

I've already tried to use constants, but it seems that this solution doesn't work in swift. I've created a `String.swift` file where I've added constants:

`let thisIsMyLonStringID = "An here I can put the long translation";`

And I can use it in this way:

`NSLocalizedString(thisIsMyLonStringID, comment: "")`

When I export to XLIFF this string is not available in the xliff files though :(

Answer (score 5):

I put here an answer with my temporary solution. It seems to work pretty well actually.

Instead of using a `Base` language for the `Localizable.strings` file I've used `English`, so I've just deselected `Base` from the file inspector -> Localizations area in Xcode and I've been prompt with a question like "which language would you like to use as base"... I've selected english.

Now I can continue using `NSLocalizedString` using a generic key and putting the translations in `Localizable.strings` when I export to xliff automatically the source is filled with the right translation and not with the key.

Comment: I have searched long for this answer! The only one that works without the super bad advice of "Use the actual string as the key".

Comment: Worked..better than other solutions

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the call to `NSLocalizedString` directly in your `Strings.swift` file. For example:

```
// Strings.swift
let myString = NSLocalizedString("some very long string", comment: "")

// Usage
print(myString)
```

That way, the string export process will be able to determine the string literal that is passed in to NSLocalizedString.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is very elegant solution to your problem. Problem is **very long string's** are getting part of our code, making it harder to read and messy.

**Solution:**
Create `LocalizationKeys.h`

```
#ifndef Project_LocalizationKeys_h
#define Project_LocalizationKeys_h

static NSString *const LocalizationKeyForVeryLongString =
@"Your Very Very Long String";

#endif
```

In your code: `ViewController.m`

```
NSLocalizedString(LocalizationKeyForVeryLongString, "");
```

So above solution separated very `long messy strings` and replaced them with `elegant and readable Key Strings`, moreover now we have separate file for key strings, so whenever someone is needed to change or to lookup, directly refer to `LocalizationKeys.h`

Comment: Actually this solution is not working for me (I'm using swift though). When I export for xliff all the keys that are not string literal are not exported. So If I use a constant like `my.key` instead of the final string `"My key"` xcode doesn't export it to xliff.

Comment: To give you some more context. I've used a generic Strings.swift file and added some strings there using this code 

`let myVeryLongString = "this is a very long string";` 

and then I've used `NSLocalizedSrtring` as per your example... but this string doesn't get exported to the final xliff... maybe is a bug.